# C: How do you free malloc'd strings inside a 2D struct array

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have a struct like this

```
typedef struct Sentences
{
 char* str;
} sentence;
```

And 2D array of these structs

```
sentence **para;
para = (sentence**) malloc(x*sizeof(sentence*));

for (i, 0 to 10)
{
 para[i] = (sentence*)malloc(y*sizeof(sentence));

 for (j, 0 to 5)
 {
   para[i][j] = (char*)malloc(z*sizeof(char));
 }
}
```

How can I free everything?

Comment: Post your real code, `for (i, 0 to 10)` is obviously not legal.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't cast the return value of malloc in C. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free the levels in the reverse order that you allocated them. So the cells, then the inner arrays, then the outer array. eg:

```
for (i, 0 to 10)
{

 for (j, 0 to 5)
 {
   free(para[i][j]);
 }
 free(para[i]);
}
free(para);
```

I've left your weird loop syntax. You'd want to loop just as you do in your real code.